# Windows 10 UWP app how to get songs list from the device?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am working on a windows 10 universal music app and I want to convert my windows phone 8.1 silverlight app to windows 10. How do I get the list of all the songs from library in windows 10 app? 
In windows phone 8.1, I've done something like this:

```
 SongCollection collection;
 MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
 collection = library.Songs;
```

Above code doesn't work with windows 10 sdk. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Above code works only in windows phone *.

```
 SongCollection collection;
     MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
     collection = library.Songs;
```

For windows phone 8.1 and Windows 10 you should use following code

```
  var songs = (await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)).ToList();
 var albums = (await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByAlbum)).ToList();
```

The above to work you should add following capability in Package.appxmanifest file.

```
<Capabilities>

    <uap:Capability  Name="musicLibrary" />
  </Capabilities>
```